# Confusion about block-level functions in ES6

Tags: javascript

[image]

The code:

```
var a=1
console.log(a)
if(true){
    a=2
    console.log(a)
    function a(){}
    console.log(a)
    a=3
    console.log(a)
}
console.log(a)  // 2   why?
```

Who please explain why the final result here of “a” is 2?

I have read a related question:
[What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6#)
The answer is excellent.
But here I still can not understand my code……

How does the `function a(){}` work in the block-scope when I have already declared a variable of the same name(`a`) in its function-scope?

Anyway, tell me why the variable `a` was assigned the value of `2`, please.

Comment: Isn't this the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191014/why-block-assign-value-change-global-variable

Comment: Don't use `function` declaration statements inside conditional code blocks.

Comment: Very odd to have two almost identical questions about some fairly obscure semantics asked within an hour of each other as the first question by two new accounts.

Comment: Alright...it is just a coincidence. Thank you all. ╮(‵▽′)╭

Comment: This is really weird, if not even a bug. I would have expected the result to always be `1` - and at least in strict mode, it is. Sloppy mode works differently apparently.