# How JavaScript variable assigned after function declaration?

Tags: javascript

The code below logs value `a` after assignments

```js
var a = []
if (true) {
  a = 1
  function a() {}
  a = 2
  function a() {}
  a = 3
  console.log('0: ', a)
}
console.log('1: ', a)
```

I suspect the output might be:

```
0:  3
1:  3
```

But actually the code above logs

```
0:  3
1:  2
```

Why?

Comment: Does it though? Where and how exactly are you executing this?

Comment: ...this is an ES6 related change to do with block scoped functions.

Comment: @deceze the snippet does print that exact output.

Comment: @VLAZ Interestingly not for me. Safari, macOS. I get two 3s.

Comment: @deceze ah...must not support block scoped functions then. [Screenshot of my result](https://i.imgur.com/rc4nsfM.png) - Firefox on Windows 10

Comment: I get 3, 2 on Chrome latest

Comment: On Node (v14, Fedora) I also get `0:  3, 1:  2`

Comment: http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedFunctions

Comment: Related: [Why does block assigned value change global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61191014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I understand it, there are two "a" variables.

One global, and one within the scope of the brackets.

On the first assignment, you are assigning it to the global.

When you declare the "a" function. It has local scope.

It assigns the current value in "a" to the global one.

Then when you assign a value to "a" again, it assigns it to the local scope variable.

For some reason, redeclaring the function name makes it assign local variable's value to the global variable. No idea why.

```js
var a = [] // assigns to global

if (true) {
  a = 1 // assigns to global
  function a() {} // pushes value to global and creates a local "a" variable
  a = 2  // assigns to local
  function a() {} // pushes value to global
  a = 3  // assigns to local
  console.log('0: ', a) // outputs the local varaible
}
console.log('1: ', a)  // outputs the last pushed global which is 2
```

Comment: "*For some reason, redeclaring the function name makes it assign local variable's value to the global variable. No idea why.*" good old hoisting. Function declarations are always processed first `var foo= 1; function foo() {}` is processed as if `function foo() {}; var foo; foo = 1;`