# scope of variables and functions inside if block in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

Variables defined inside if block, are accessible outside the if block also

```js
console.log(name) // undefined

if (true) {
  var name = "harry"
  console.log(name) // harry
}

console.log(name) // harry
```

I got this:

```js
if (true) {
  sayHello() // hello
  
  function sayHello() {
    console.log("hello")
  }

  sayHello() // hello
}

sayHello() // hello
```

Got this too.

But what's happening here

```js
sayHello() // TypeError: sayHello is not a function

if (true) {
  sayHello()

  function sayHello() {
    console.log("hello")
  }

  sayHello()
}

sayHello()
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var
have a look at this page

Comment: With ES6 functions are now block scoped. "*variables defined inside if block, are accessible outside the if block also*" that is *only* true for `var` declared variables.

Comment: Have a look at the differences between strict and non-strict mode as suggested above and know the differences between var, let and const. Also, spend some time understanding how hoisting works in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Hoisting of function declarations inside blocks has confusing semantics.

The last code example is similar to the code as shown below:

```
var sayHello1;
sayHello1();   

if (true) {
  let sayHello2 = function() {
     console.log("hello");
  }

  sayHello2();

  // assigned to outer variable at the place
  // of function declaration in your code
  sayHello1 = sayHello2;

  sayHello2();
}

sayHello1()
```

As seen in the above code, there are actually two variables in your code: one inside the block is a `let` declaration and one outside the block is a `var` declaration.

Variable defined outside the block is assigned the function declared inside the block at the place where it is actually defined in your code.

Invoking the outer `sayHello1` variable as a function *before* it is assigned the function inside the block will throw an error.

**Related Questions:**

1. [Why does block assigned value change global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191014/why-does-block-assigned-value-change-global-variable)
2. [confused about function declaration in { }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58619924/confused-about-function-declaration-in)
3. [What are the precise semantics of block-level functions in ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419897/what-are-the-precise-semantics-of-block-level-functions-in-es6)

Comment: No, function declarations are hoisted. Hoisting of function declaration is a bit different as explained in my answer and the related questions listed at the end of my answer.

Comment: sorry, I meant function expression

Comment: yes, function expressions are not hoisted.

Answer (score 0):

If we check the global execution context for the code, the "sayHello" on line 1 is hoisted and assigned as a variable and not as a function resulting in the type error.
If we do the following modification in the code, we will get the sayHello as undefined and the code will not give the type error.
Below is the code for the same.

```
console.log(sayHello) // prints "undefined" and not the type error.

if (true) {
  sayHello()

  function sayHello() {
    console.log("hello")
  }

  sayHello()
}

sayHello()
```