# function hoisting - why is my function not defined properly?

Tags: javascript, function, hoisting

```js
function goo(){
    console.log(foo)
    console.log(foo())
    {
        function foo() {return 'im foo'}
        
    }
}
goo()
```

I'm trying to see where the foo function definition is hoisted to when it's inside a block.

I've learnt that in non-strict mode a function definition is hoisted to the top of function scope.
So I expected the foo function to be defined right after goo() is executed cuz I expect it to be hoisted to the top of the goo function.

After the hoisted definition of foo, console.log(foo) and console.log(foo()) would run and I expected it to each give me a function definition and 'im foo'.

But what ended up happening is that the console says foo is initialized to undefined and foo is not a function. I thought initalization to undefined only happened when a var variable is hoisted. When function definition is hoisted, don't they define themselves? I'm not sure why foo is defined to undefined. Console didn't raise a reference error that says foo is not declared. foo is declared alright but console says it's not a function. **Why is it initalized to undefined when I wrote it to be a function that returns 'im foo' in the definition?**

```js
function goo(){
    console.log(foo)
    console.log(foo())
    function foo() {return 'im foo'}
        
    
}
goo()
```

I expected it to run like this code above. The only difference between the two is that foo function is defined inside a block. **But why would there be a difference between the two if the foo function is hoisted to the top of goo function? Does this mean I was wrong about function definition being hoisted to top of function scope?**

Comment: functions inside blocks are [handled differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68736679/scope-of-variables-and-functions-inside-if-block-in-javascript)

Comment: You're not *wrong*. Just missing the fact that since ES6 there are block scoped functions. Which then interact weirdly with other stuff due to web compatibility semantics.

Comment: @VLAZ can you specify what u said? Do you mean in ES6 now all function definitions are block scoped?

Comment: @Hanrabong http://es6-features.org/#BlockScopedFunctions

Answer (score 0):

Both the functions **foo()** and **goo()** are hoisted during the interpretation phase, but the only catch is that **foo** is kept inside a block scope and hence access is not possible and you receive an error.
Remember that, Block Level Scoping always affects identifier resolution(nothing to do with `Hoisting`). In this example, the function declarations are defined and hoisted but a function declared within a block may or may not be available outside the block.

Answer (score -1):

By definition hoisting only happens for the block.

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#:~:text=JavaScript%20Hoisting%20refers%20to%20the%20process%20whereby%20the%20interpreter%20appears%20to%20move%20the%20declaration%20of%20functions%2C%20variables%20or%20classes%20to%20the%20top%20of%20their%20scope%2C%20prior%20to%20execution%20of%20the%20code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20Hoisting%20refers%20to%20the%20process%20whereby%20the%20interpreter%20appears%20to%20move%20the%20declaration%20of%20functions%2C%20variables%20or%20classes%20to%20the%20top%20of%20their%20scope%2C%20prior%20to%20execution%20of%20the%20code).

Specifically for functions:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#conditionally_created_functions

Comment: This may or may not be the right answer; as written, it’s more of a comment possibly.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function goo(){
    console.log(foo)
    console.log(foo())
    {
        alert(1)
        function foo() {return 'im foo'}
        
    }
}
goo()
```

is equal to :

```js
function goo(){
    console.log(foo)
    console.log(foo())
    {
        function foo() {return 'im foo'}
        alert(1)
        
    }
}
goo()
```

but not equal to :

```js
function goo(){
    {
        function foo() {return 'im foo'}
        alert(1)
        
    }
    console.log(foo)
    console.log(foo())
}
goo()
```

Answer (score -2):

You can initialize your function before call it to resolve "something is not a function" error

```
function goo() {  
          function foo() {
           return "im foo"
   }     
  console.log(foo);   
  console.log(foo()); 
  } 
goo();
```